# writing to SQL and file after form post

Tags: php, sql, forms, file

With the code below I am writing to a database. How would I and in a secondary write to file on server option after sql insert has completed?

```
extract($_GET);
$valid_input = true;
if($cronsafe != 'mRT0SmaUDzDv2'){
    $valid_input = false;
    echo 'Error';
    die();
}

if(strlen($name) == 0){
    $valid_input = false;
    echo 'not valid';
    die();
}

if(strlen($email) == 0){
    $valid_input = false;
    echo 'not valid';
    die();
}
if(strlen($phone) == 0){
    $valid_input = false;
    echo 'not valid';
    die();
}
if(strlen($company) == 0){
    $valid_input = false;
    echo 'not valid';
    die();
}


if($valid_input):
    $compilerConfig = 'includes/config.php';
    if (file_exists($compilerConfig)) {
        include($compilerConfig);
    }
    
    
    require_once $mageFilename;
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($localFile);
    $conn = mysqli_connect($hostname_conn,$username_conn,$password_conn,$database_conn);
    $idx = md5($email.date("Y-m-d").$current_url);
    
    $insert_sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO `cms_page_track` ( `name`, `email`,`company`,`phone`, `idx`,`cms_page`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)" );
    $insert_sql->bind_param("ssssss", $name, $email,$company,$phone,$idx,$current_url);
    
    if(!$insert_sql->execute()) :
        echo '0';
    else:
        echo '1';
    endif;

endif;
```

Comment: You write to the file in the same way as in any other script. The SQL query doesn't make any difference.

Comment: What's the point of setting `$valid_input = false;` if you always call `die()`? You'll never get to the `if ($valid_input)` line.

Comment: @Barmar thanks i will remove that